# How to install mobogenie in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I want to download android apps. Previously I used mobogeine in windows.

How to install mobogenie in Ubuntu 14.04? Is there any similar application in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Wine.
Wine enables Linux, Mac, FreeBSD, and Solaris users to run Windows applications without a copy of Microsoft Windows. Wine is free software under constant development.
You may get an older version of it in Ubuntu Software Center.
After installing Wine, install the .exe file of Mobogenie via it.
If you've got a machine which has atleast 2 GB of RAM and a fast enough processor it should run smoothly.

Comment: You should give the command for installing the newer version through apt-get